# AirportData, GeoNearest and filtering data

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I bought a Raspberry Pi, which introduced me to Mathematica, and I'm just diving in. I'm guessing my question is really a basic syntax question, but I don't know how to unravel it.

I thought I would play with the airport data to start with. I understand how to use GeoNearest to find nearby airports. But I would like to filter out heliports. The easiest way to do that is look for runway lengths greater than some value, lets say 2000 ft.

So...how can I get a list of Airport entities with a property of LongestRunwayLength>=2000 ft, and feed that list into the GeoNearest function to find the 5 closest such aiports to wherever specified?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't get it to work, but it should be something like: `GeoNearest[EntityClass[
  "Airport",
  "LongestRunwayLength" -> Quantity[Interval[{500, 50000}], "Meters"]
  ], Here, 5]` (meters could be replaced by feet.) Check out the documentation for `Entity` to read more about implicit entities, which is key here.

Comment: Perhaps something like this might be a way to go:    Select[GeoNearest["Airport",Santa Barbara (city),{All,Quantity[100,"Miles"]}],!StringContainsQ[#["Name"],"Heli"]&]

Comment: `Select[GeoNearest["Airport",Santa Barbara (city),{All,Quantity[100,"Miles"]}],!StringContainsQ[#["Name"],{"Heli","Blimp","Amphibious"}]&] `

Comment: More along your use of runway length, however I am not sure an easy way to assure getting 5 results for any location. As you expand search radius you possible get more airports, but plenty of places on Earth where radius would have to be very large to get 5 results of any kind: `Take[Select[GeoNearest["Airport",Santa Barbara (city),{All,Quantity[30,"Miles"]}],#["LongestRunwayLength"]>  Quantity[2000., "Feet"]&],UpTo[5]]`

Comment: @Dave, isn't that how GeoNearest works? You specify a count and you get x nearest, no matter the distance?

To both of you, thanks for the guidance. Hopefully I'll pick it up tonight or tomorrow night. 

@ C.E., that syntax is interesting, and matches how I was guessing it might work. How do I think about / read the -> operator?

Comment: This worked for me: Select[GeoNearest["Airport", 
  Interpreter["City"]["Scottsdale Arizona"]], ! 
   StringContainsQ[#["Name"], {"Heli", "Blimp", "Amphibious"}] &]